# Where do I put the sum function to sum sick leave days in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

The query shown below gives me the number of leave days excluding Saturday and Sunday. My problem is I don't know where to put the sum() function to sum all leave days.

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(eleave.resume_date , eleave.leave_date) as total_days , ( 
 ABS(DATEDIFF(eleave.leave_date, eleave.resume_date)) - 
 ABS(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(eleave.leave_date, INTERVAL 1 - 
 DAYOFWEEK(eleave.leave_date) DAY) , ADDDATE(eleave.resume_date, INTERVAL 
1  - DAYOFWEEK(eleave.resume_date) DAY))) / 7 * 2 - 
 (DAYOFWEEK(IF(eleave.resume_date < eleave.leave_date , leave.resume_date, 
eleave.leave_date)) = 1) - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(eleave.resume_date > 
eleave.leave_date, eleave.resume_date, eleave.leave_date)) = 7)) as 
leavedays , employee.emp_lname , type.typ_name as leavetype , 
education.qualification , education.program FROM employee INNER JOIN eleave on employee.emp_num = eleave.emp_num LEFT JOIN type ON type.typ_id = 
eleave.typ_id left join education ON employee.emp_num = education.emp_num 
 WHERE employee.emp_num = 4774 AND type.typ_name = 'Sick leave'
```

Comment: You can sum(.....) leavedays with the appropriate group by clause after the where clause.

Comment: I do it  as advised sum() as leavedays ........ where employee.emp_num = 4774 AND type.type_name = 'Sick leave' GROUP BY totaldays, leavedays. The sick leave days are not summed up any sql correction for it

Comment: Your GROUP BY should be: GROUP BY total_days, employee.emp_lname, type.typ_name, education.qualification, education.program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the sum per employee to get total leaves for each employee

it will look like this

```
SELECT employee.emp_num, 
SUM (ABS(DATEDIFF(eleave.leave_date, eleave.resume_date)) -  ABS(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(eleave.leave_date, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(eleave.leave_date) DAY) , ADDDATE(eleave.resume_date, INTERVAL 1  - DAYOFWEEK(eleave.resume_date) DAY))) / 7 * 2 - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(eleave.resume_date < eleave.leave_date , leave.resume_date, eleave.leave_date)) = 1) - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(eleave.resume_date > eleave.leave_date, eleave.resume_date, eleave.leave_date)) = 7)) as leavedays 

FROM employee INNER JOIN eleave on employee.emp_num = eleave.emp_num 
LEFT JOIN type ON type.typ_id = eleave.typ_id left join education 
ON employee.emp_num = education.emp_num 
WHERE employee.emp_num = 4774 AND type.typ_name = 'Sick leave'
GROUP BY employee.emp_num
```